# How to extract which combination of regex match from my pattern?

Tags: java, regex

Suppose my regex is this

```
Pattern ANIMALS =  Pattern.compile("boy|dog|cat|hen")
```

and my String is

```
String = "The boy is good";
```

as `"boy"` is present in my pattern it will match but Is there any way that it will return back "boy" to me. Please kindly don't suggest that make a Set or ArrayList and match this with contains method as my pattern is very huge what I used is just a very tiny example.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'return back "boy" to me', isn't it a call to `group()` after a successful `find()` of `Matcher` object?

Comment: If you have seen the actual scenario which I edited in my question you would have understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `matcher.group()` method once you get `Matcher` out of that `Pattern`

```
Matcher m = ANIMALS.matcher("The boy is good");
while(m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group());
}
```